# JPA Inheritance mapping - Making a field optional in 1 subclass, mandatory in another

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, inheritance

I have a entity in the application I am working for that has two versions.

I have mapped the entity using JPA inheritance mapping so that there are now two classes, let's call them Contract and OtherContract. They both have a couple of shared fields, defined in BaseContract. Both classes inherit from that base class.

The problem now is that of those shared fields, some should be mandatory (as in have a not null constraint in the database) in the "Contract" class but optional in "OtherContract".

What I could do is duplicate all of the fields from the shared class in both classes and modify the annotations accordingly but that seems hard to manage.

(like this:)

```
public class Contract extends BaseContract {
    @Column(nullable = true)
    private String name;
}

public class OtherContract extends BaseContract {
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
}
```

I could also make all the fields non-mandatory and add the validation in my domain layer (which I'll do anyway). I like this a little better but the database tables will have all the fields optional which I don't like.

The inheritance type I will probably have to use is TABLE_PER_CLASS

Does anyone know a solution without these drawbacks?

Comment: What is your inheritance strategy? What do you mean by mandatory?

Comment: I have updated my question, thanks.

Comment: You can define the field in the parent and use `@AttributeOverride` at the class level  to redefine the column in the subclasses.